# Minimax Algorithm for Tic-Tac-Toe not responding as expected

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, dynamic-programming, tic-tac-toe, minimax

I recently decided to try and implement a very basic API to return the best move for a game of tic-tac-toe. I wanted to, as much as possible, write and implement the code myself. I have what I thought was a good solution, but it doesn't respond by trying to block its opponent from winning, and doesn't seem to work much at all for its intended purpose. I'm less looking for the correct answer (I could have easily copied another program and called it a day) and more *why* my code isn't responding as I'd expect. I'll include some notes underneath the code snippet.

```py
def player(board: list[str | None]):
    """Returns the next player for a given board
    
    Assumes that X goes first for any given game
    """
    if board.count("X") > board.count("O"):
        return "O"
    return "X"


def result_of_move(board: list[str | None], move:int) -> list[str | None]:
    """Returns resultant board from a given move, based on current player
        
    <move> parameter must be an integer 0-8 (inclusive)
    Player move determined by player()
    For use by opponent models in determining resultant actions
    """
    if (move not in range(9)) or (board[move] != None):
        raise Exception("Invalid move!")

    board_copy = deepcopy(board)
    board_copy[move] = player(board)
    
    return board_copy


def available_actions(board: list[str | None]) -> list[int]:
    """Returns available move indices given a board state. 
    
    Agnostic to which player's turn it is, for use by opponent models to 
    populate search pahts
    """
    options = []
    for i, x in enumerate(board):
        if x is None:
            options.append(i)
    return options

def winner(board: list[str | None]):
    """Takes a board and returns winner if any, else None"""
    win_states = [
        [0, 1, 2],
        [3, 4, 5],
        [6, 7, 8],
        [0, 3, 6],
        [1, 4, 7],
        [2, 5, 8],
        [0, 4, 8],
        [2, 4, 6]
    ]
    
    for line in win_states:
        a, b, c = line
        if board[a] and board[a] == board[b] == board[c]:
            return board[a]
    return None
    

def is_terminal(board: list[str | None]) -> bool:
    """Returns whether game is over or not
    
    To be used as a base case check for recursive opponent models
    """
    if None not in board:
        return True
    if winner(board):
        return True
    return False

def board_utility(board: list[str | None]):
    if winner(board) == "X":
        return 1
    elif winner(board) == "O":
        return -1
    else:
        return 0


def minmax(board: list[str | None]):
    """Returns the optimal move value and index based on board input board
    
    This implements the minmax algorithm *without* alpha-beta pruning or depth-, 
    limiting, using full depth-first search. X is assumed the maximizing player
    """

    def max_value(board):
        value = -2
        move = None
        
        for action in available_actions(board):
            res = result_of_move(board, action)
            if is_terminal(res):
                return (board_utility(res), action)
            
            v = max(min_value(res)[0], value)
            
            if v >= value:
                value = v
                move = action
        return (value, move)
    
    def min_value(board):
        value = 2
        move = None
        
        for action in available_actions(board):
            res = result_of_move(board, action)
            if is_terminal(res):
                return (board_utility(res), action)
            
            v = min(max_value(res)[0], value)
            
            if v <= value:
                value = v
                move = action
        return (value, move)
        
    if is_terminal(board):
        return None
    
    if player(board) == "X":
        return max_value(board)[1]
    else:
        return min_value(board)[1]
```

I imagine that the issue comes from the recursive calls to minmax(), and the data being passed as it moves up and down the chain. This is the third implementation I've tried, and I admit I'm a little burnt out and am unable to follow the logic in its current state.

I also recognize that most implementations of this do not use a single list, but rather nested lists representing each of the board's rows. I don't *think* that this is the source of my issues, but if it is and anyone can explain, I'd love to learn more about this.

When playing a game, I play in the center. The model responds by playing in the top left. I move bottom right, it plays middle top. When I move top right, it does not respond with middle right as one would expect, blocking my winning move, and instead plays middle left. I think there's either an issue with how the data is passed between calls, or the manner in which it's choosing a move is flawed.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. We don't provide debugging services. The following references give advice on debugging your code. [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), [Six Debugging Techniques for Python Programmers](https://medium.com/techtofreedom/six-debugging-techniques-for-python-programmers-cb25a4baaf4b)  or [Ultimate Guide to Python Debugging](https://towardsdatascience.com/ultimate-guide-to-python-debugging-854dea731e1b)

Comment: @user3386109 correct. The model is meant to read the board state and determine the player whose turn it currently is, and make a move based on that. You’ll notice the `player(board)` function, and the use of that function in the `minmax()` function

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this part of the `max_value` function:

```
        v = max(min_value(res)[0], value)
        
        if v >= value:
            value = v
            move = action
```

The `if` condition will always be true, since by calling `max`, you ensured that `v` is never less than `value`. If the last considered action happens to be a bad move, then still the `if` block will mark it as the best move, forgetting about the earlier action that was better.

The solution is simple... don't call `max`, but let `v` be the actual value you get back from recursion. The "max" effect is taken care of by the `if` construct. So:

```
        v = min_value(res)[0]
        
        if v >= value:
            value = v
            move = action
```

A similar correction is needed in `min_value`.